# Tarantool - AUTOINCREMENT equivalent?

Tags: tarantool

During my first steps with Tarantool I am wondering how to do basic things.

Imagine that I am storing the following registers:

```
s:insert(1,'{"name": "foo name", "phone": "foo phone"}')
s:insert(2,'{"name": "barname", "phone": "bar phone"}')
```

Is there something similar to autoincrement primary key in SQL databases so I do not need to enumerate the indexes?

Something like not specifying the primary index at all in Tarantool 1.6.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a (deprecated) auto_increment function, which you could use like:`box.space.bigspace:auto_increment{'Fld#1', 'Fld#2'}`.

Fld#1 and Fld#2 are the contents to place into a new tuple.
See [here](https://tarantool.org/doc/1.7/book/box/box_space.html#box-space-auto-increment). Since Tarantool 1.7.5, it is recommended to use [sequences](https://tarantool.org/doc/1.7/book/box/data_model.html#sequences) though, which are interesting in that they let you specify how you'd like your keys generated. Basically once you set up a sequence, you assign it to a space, and it autoincrements whenever you add a new tuple.